# Need to find the outer boundary size of droplets in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

[image: Droplet Images]

i am trying to find the outer boundary size of all drops along length of tube using python.

I am struggling to distinguish between outer and inner boundary after canny edge detection.can anyone help me please.

The image preproccessing i have used is like:

```
# load the image, convert it to grayscale, and blur it slightly
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(imc, (5, 5), 0)
# perform edge detection, then perform a dilation + erosion to
# close gaps in between object edges
dilate = cv2.dilate(gray, None, iterations=1)
#cv2.imshow('dilated',dilate)
erode = cv2.erode(dilate, None, iterations=1)
#cv2.imshow('eroded',erode)
edged = cv2.Canny(erode,230,230)
#cv2.imshow('%deroded' %count,edged)
```

1. This code gives me inner edges easily but i want outer edges.
2. You can see droplet boundary is sufficiently thick and varies from case to case.
3. I have to process 4000 images in a sequence.please guide me.
4. i am unable to distinguish between droplet boundary and tube boundary.

How to eliminate inner edges and filter  outer edges only?

[image: expected output image i want to improve]

above one is near expected output.

Comment: You might want to provide the expected output image for clarity. Nice microfluidic droplets btw ;)

Comment: when asking a question, make sure you post it with good tags because even if you add them when your question is a day old, most people won't see it anymore -- you could try thresholding (or not), followed by morphology (opening or closing) which will hopefully leave the thick dark borders of the droplets, while erasing all narrower dark features

Answer (score 2):

[image]
A thresholding step and refined threshold values for your canny will provide only the outer edges. I performed preliminary histogram analysis data exploration (see OpenCV's [calcHist](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-calchist-method/) function for further details) to gauge these threshold values.

Once you perform a thresholding step you can use either the thresholded image or the canny result to find contours, as seen in the image above.

If you still find both inner and outer edges in the future, I'd suggest grouping contours by their bounding box center, then filtering out smaller contours that share a similar center with a bigger contour of mildly larger area.

```
# gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(im, (5, 5), 0)

dilate = cv2.dilate(gray, None, iterations=1)
erode  = cv2.erode(dilate, None, iterations=1)

_, thresh = cv2.threshold(erode, 108, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
edged    = cv2.Canny(thresh, 144, 250)

canny_cnts, _  = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
thresh_cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(255-thresh[:,:,0], cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

f, ax = plt.subplots(3,1,figsize=(20,7))

for a, i, t in zip(ax, [erode, thresh, edged], ['Eroded', 'Thresholded', 'Canny']):
    a.imshow(i, 'gray')
    a.axis('off')
    a.set_title(t)

for a, cnts in zip(ax[1:], [thresh_cnts, canny_cnts]):
    for cnt, col in zip([ c[:,0] for c in cnts ], colors):
        a.plot( cnt[:,0], cnt[:,1], color=col, lw=2)
```